# Merging a list of lists such that unique values overwrite nonunique ones?

Tags: python, list, merge, multidimensional-array

After searching around for quite a while and trying to come up with a solution on my own with list comprehensions, I feel like I've been completely stumped on how to solve the following problem:

Given a list:

```
crazy_list = [a, b]
```

Where:

```
a = [['*'], ['*', '34', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '102', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '170', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '238', '*'], ['*']]
b = [['*'], ['*', '*', '*', '102', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '170', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '238', '*'], ['*', '34', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*']]
```

How do I elegantly get a new list of lists such that:

```
answer = [['*'], ['*', '34', '*', '102', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '102', '*', '170', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '170', '*', '238', '*'], ['*', '34', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '238', '*'], ['*']]
```

and how would I generalize this kind of merging to do the same for:

```
[a, b, c, etc...]
```

(c and onwards would have the same number of elements and subelements as 'a' and 'b', but would probably have different unique values in different positions)

====================v The little that I've been able to do so far v=====================

I can come up with a list comprehension that does do what I want for individual lists with something like:

```
c = ['*', '34', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
d = ['*', '*', '*', '102', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
```

by doing:

```
[c[item_indx] if item != '*' else d[item_indx] for item_indx, item in enumerate(c)]
```

but even trying to generalize what I have so far is giving me one heck of a headache...
I'm probably approaching this problem incorrectly. Some help and/or thoughts on how to solve/better-approach this problem would be much appreciated. Also, I can't just ditch the '*'s as they encode important timing information. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: what about conflicts in the same position while merging?

Comment: If a unique value aka (a number string) already exists after a merge then any other numbers that occur in the same positions in successive merges shouldn't overwrite. Only '*'s should be getting overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's figure out how to merge a sublist from `a` with a sublist from `b`:

```
[x if x != '*' else y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
```

We take pairs of items from the two lists, and for each pair, produce one or the other element, and make a list of the results.

To generalize that to multiple lists: well, `zip` accepts `*args`, so there's no problem there - we can make tuples of items from any number of lists. But then we need to take "the non-'*' element, if it exists, otherwise '*'" from that tuple.

One way to do that is to make a `set` of the elements, remove `'*'`, and use any element from the result (if non-empty), otherwise use `'*'`. We can get "any element" from a `set` with `.pop()`, which will raise a KeyError if the set is empty. So we make a wrapper function and then use it:

```
def non_star_if_possible(items):
    try: return set(items).difference('*').pop()
    except KeyError: return '*'

def merge(lists):
    return [non_star_if_possible(items) for items in zip(*lists)]
```

Finally, we actually have a list of lists of lists, and we want to take lists from the lists of lists, element-wise. So we apply the same `zip` trick:

```
def merge_all(data):
    return [merge(lists) for lists in zip(*data)]
```

And if we prefer, we could fold those last two into a single nested list comprehension, but you might find it clearer this way. :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Took me a few minutes to wrap my head around what you were doing, but it makes sense now that I've digested it. I should add that I greatly appreciated the explanation as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your progress on just two lists so far works, you can try this.

```
def merge(a, b):
    return [a[item_indx] if item != '*' else b[item_indx] for item_indx, item in enumerate(a)]

reduce(merge, crazy_list)
```

What `reduce` does in this case is take the resulting list of the last merge and then does it with the next element. So for a crazy list of [a, b, c, d], a and b will merge, and the resulting list will merge with c, and that result will merge with d. And so forth. In general, `reduce` applies the function supplied as an argument in a comparable fashion.

**Edit:** Okay, I see what you were saying now. So I defined another method to handle lists of lists. I realize you've already accepted an answer, but I'll just leave this as an alternative.

```
# a and b are lists of lists.
def merge_lists(a, b):
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = merge(a[i], b[i])
    return a

reduce(merge_lists, (c, d))
```

Comment: hmmm, that's quite interesting, maybe if I experiment with it some more, I might be able to come up with something... The solution you posted doesn't work because the list comprehension I posted only works on single lists, not on a list of lists and definitely not on a list containing a list of lists (oh god that's an awkward way to say it)

Comment: It works on a list of lists for me. Can you explain why it doesn't work? And what's the behavior you would expect for a list of lists of lists? When I added another list `a` (in addition to `c` and `d` in your example), `a = ['69', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']`. `reduce(merge, [c,d,a])` produced `['69', '34', '*', '102', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']`. Is that wrong?

Comment: hmm... so for the list of lists if I do something like:    for indx, value in enumerate(a):
 merge(a[indx],b[indx]) that works for me.

Comment: I didn't even know about reduce before, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Another version

```
reduce(lambda a,b:[[x[0] if x[1] == '*' else x[1] for x in p] 
   for p in (zip(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)) ],(a,b))
```

for multiple lists

```
reduce(lambda a,b:[[x[0] if x[1] == '*' else x[1] for x in p] 
   for p in (zip(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)) ],(a,b,c.....))
```

or may be this

```
reduce(lambda a,b:[[x[x[1] != '*'] for x in p]
   for p in (zip(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)) ],(a,b,c,....))
```

Note: [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reduce#reduce) Applies the two lambda function over the iterator passing the result as the first argument of the next call.

The [lambda](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) function [zips](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reduce#zip) both the list and for each item of the list selects the non '*' item giving preference to the first list in case of a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

a solution for any number of list:

```
from functools import reduce

a = ['a','*','*','*']
b = ['*','b','*','*']
c = ['*','*','*','c']

ls = (a, b, c)

def merge(*ls):
    return [f(x) for x in zip(*ls)]

def f(x):
    for item in x:
        if item != '*':
            return item
    return '*'

print(reduce(merge, ls))
```

this gives (py3.2, idleX !)

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
['a', 'b', '*', 'c']
>>>
```